# Protege ontology structure

Tags: owl, protege

I'm trying to build a very simlpe ontology to represent an RPG game with protege and owl.
I'm fairly new to ontologies so probably I'm not really getting many things (for example, the open world assumption I suppose).

Here you can download it -> [LINK](http://pastebin.com/nfHeeaqA)

There are two type of unit classes, enchanters and melee fighters.
Enchanters are split in arcane magic and divine magic.
Spells are divided in 4 schools (evocation, healing, elemental, protection).
Arcane magic enchanters can use only elemental and evocation spells, divine magic enchanters only the other two.
Units can have a single class.
Units, spells and unit classes are individuals.

There are a number of queries that I'd like to execute but do not return anything, for example:

1. canCast some ArcaneMagicSpell
   Expected: List of unit classes that can cast arcane spells.
   Returns: The unit classes, but I also want the units (individuals).
2. canCast value SpellFireball
   Expected: List of unit classes that can cast fireballs.
   Returns: Nothing.
3. canBeCastedBy some ArcaneMagicClass
   Expected: All spells castable by an arcane mage.
   Returns:: Nothing.
4. canBeCastedBy value UnitClassBlackMage
   Expected: All spells that a black mage can cast.
   Returns: Nothing.
5. hasClass some (canCast some Spell)
   Expected: All the unit that can cast a particular spell.
   Returns: Nothing.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here but I really don't get it. How can improve my ontology to support those queries (or better formed queries to get the same expected results)?

Comment: This was also asked, verbatim, on answers.semanticweb.com in [this question](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/19900/protege-ontology-structure) with an accepted answer.  A [very similar question](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-owl/2012-November/019164.html) was also asked at about the same time on the protege-owl mailing list.

Comment: Yes I asked there after I got no feedback here.

Comment: I expected that the same user (you) posted in both places.  My comment was more for the sake of other people who come to see the answer;  now they have a link to a place where the question was answered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for answers.semanticweb.com, and received an answer there.


Comment: Did you make any progress with this?  (I know there was an answer on answers.semanticweb.com, and some replies on the mailling list.)  If you did, it would be worthwhile post an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I made some progress but soon after I had to interrupt this project. I might as well delete this question.